# Basic questions about fields and ordered fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have some basic questions about fields.

Let $(\mathbb K,\oplus,\odot)$ be a field.

1. Are there any fields which don't have $0$ as additive identity or $1$ as multiplicative identity?
   Are there any fields not covering $0$ or $1$?
2. In some literature they write $0_{\mathbb K}$ instead of $0$ and $1_{\mathbb K}$ instead of $1$.
   So what does $n_{\mathbb{K}}$ mean and what is the difference between $n_{\mathbb K}$ and $n$?
3. Are the operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$ always addition and multiplication?

Assume you have an ordered field $\mathbb F$. If I read about ordered fields I always read about positives and negatives. But does an ordered field have to contain negatives? Is this implication necessary: $a\in \mathbb F \Rightarrow -a\in \mathbb F$?

Comment: To answer your first question, $0$ is just a placeholder for the additive identity. Similar for $1$. It does not mean $0,1 \in \mathbb{R}$. So, a field by definition has to have these $0,1$ placeholders.

Comment: A finite field cannot be an ordered field. Is there a reason for including that tag? I don't see any algebraic topology here either. Removing the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions can be answered in the more general setting of (unital) rings - a field is simply a commutative ring whose elements are all invertible.

A ring has to have identities for addition and multiplication (it is an abelian group under addition, monoid under multiplication). By convention, these are 0 and 1. A field is a ring, so to answer your first question, almost-yes. There are conceptual ideas like [the field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element) but these are not fields in the classical sense.

I would guess $n_\mathbb{K}$ simply refers to $1_\mathbb{K} + \dots + 1_\mathbb{K}$ with $n$ summands. The difference is that there may not be an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in your field (let alone $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$) - for example, take $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $n = 3$. Under the above notation $3_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}} = 1_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$.

The operations are always called 'addition' and 'multiplication', but the terminology for this comes from the fact that we come up with the abstract definition of a 'ring' to generalise the arithmetic properties of e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$.

Finally, if $a \in R$ then under the abelian group structure of $(R,\oplus)$, there must exist an additive inverse $b$ for which $a + b = 0_R$. We can relabel $b$ by $-a$.